# An Easy Way to Split multiple String using Transact-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 strings

```
@NameList = Hi|Hi1|Hi2
@DESCLIST = Hii|Hii1|Hii2
@SEQList = 1|2|3
```

I am looking for a Transact-SQL function where it can split these strings and insert in to table in below order

```
pkid  Name   DESC   Seq
1     Hi     Hii    1
2     Hi1    Hii1   2
3     Hi2    Hii2   3
```

Comment: So look for a split function that returns an index column and split and join three times on the index column. There are a ton of questions and answers on this site about splitting strings in SQL Server

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

As Martin Smith suggested, you just need to use a string splitting function and `join` the results together:

```
declare @NameList nvarchar(100) = 'Hi|Hi1|Hi2';
declare @DESCLIST nvarchar(100) = 'Hii|Hii1|Hii2';
declare @SEQList nvarchar(100) = '1|2|3';

select s1.item as Name
      ,s2.item as [Desc]
      ,s3.item as Seq
from dbo.fn_StringSplit(@NameList,'|',null) as s1
    join dbo.fn_StringSplit(@DESCLIST,'|',null) as s2
      on s1.rn = s2.rn
    join dbo.fn_StringSplit(@SEQList,'|',null) as s3
      on s1.rn = s3.rn;
```

Results:

```
+------+------+------+-----+
| pkid | Name | Desc | Seq |
+------+------+------+-----+
|    1 | Hi   | Hii  |   1 |
|    2 | Hi1  | Hii1 |   2 |
|    3 | Hi2  | Hii2 |   3 |
+------+------+------+-----+
```

---

String Split Function:

```
create function [dbo].[fn_StringSplit]
(
    @str nvarchar(max) = ' '            -- String to split.
    ,@delimiter as nvarchar(255) = ','  -- Delimiting value to split on.
    ,@num as int = null                 -- Which value to return, null returns all.
)
returns table
as
    return
    (
        with d as
        (
            select rn = row_number() over (order by (select null))
                    ,item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
            from(select x = convert(xml, '<i>'
                                    + replace((select @str for xml path('')), @delimiter, '</i><i>')
                                    + '</i>'
                                    ).query('.')
                ) AS a
                    cross apply x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
        )
        select rn
                ,item
        from d
        where rn = @num
            or @num is null
    );
```

Comment: Thank you very much
Your Function is very clear and very understandable manner

Comment: @srikanthreddykarumuri  No worries.  If this is the correct answer to your question, for the benefit of others with the same problem, kindly mark the my answer as such.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the function:

```
STRING_SPLIT (string, separator)
```

with table values that divides a string into rows of substrings, according to a specified separator character and would return the records by assigning them an id through the Row_number function that returns a sequential number to each row within a partition of a result set:

```
DECLARE @NameList VARCHAR(50) = 'Hi|Hi1|Hi2'
DECLARE @DESCLIST VARCHAR(50) = 'Hii|Hii1|Hii2'
DECLARE @SEQList VARCHAR(50) = '1|2|3'  

select namelist.name,DESCLIST.descr, SEQList.SEQ from
  (select value as name ,row_number() over (order by (select null)) as id  from STRING_SPLIT(@NameList,'|')  ) 
  namelist inner join 
  (select value as descr    ,row_number() over (order by (select null))  as id  from STRING_SPLIT(@DESCLIST,'|')  ) 
  DESCLIST  on namelist.id = DESCLIST.id inner join
  (select value as SEQ      ,row_number() over (order by (select null)) as id  from STRING_SPLIT(@SEQList,'|')) 
  SEQList  on DESCLIST.id = SEQList.id
```